# Selector for unattributed text?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**This is impossible, disregard this question. Thanks for all the help.**

Is there any way to select the text for something like this, and for the example we'll say I want to select the text **duck**:

```
<div id="derp">
  <a class="irrelevant">duck cat woof</a>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Edit: Apparently it felt like adding a jquery tag. Just css, sorry. 
Edit again:

> Short answer: not with css. What are you trying to do anyway? Add some context please. – Till 1 min ago

On reddit you have an ability to change the css of your 'subreddit'. But you can't alter any of the other code, only the stylesheet. So I basically want to be able to select a word of text that is unattributed within a div and be able to use content with a pseudoselector to add an image / text before or after some text matching 'xxx'.

Comment: Short answer: not with css. What are you trying to do anyway? Add some context please. Edit: Woops, where did that jquery tag come from now?

Comment: Edited, Till. (Not sure how to reply so I hope this gets to you).

Answer (score 0):

Without using the ID or class, you could select it with `$('div a').text()`.  This will give you the text of the first `a` in the first `div`.

Without any attributes there will be no way to specify a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$('#derp').children('a').val();
```

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately it chose to slip a jquery tag in without me noticing, much appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the surrounding HTML. Is the `a` element the only child of `#derp`?

```
#derp > a /* a being the only a child */
#derp > a:first-of-type /* a being the first child */
```

You might also be able to use the attribute selectors:

```
#derp > *[attr="val"]
```

Check out the [W3Cs Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) document for all available CSS3 selectors.

Comment: Sorry I can see how I haven't been entirely clear here. I need to have the actual text 'duck' selected. But I guess that's impossible.

Comment: Yes, that is impossible in CSS.

Comment: Ah, shame. Much appreciated all the same mate.